# How to prevent mousemove after mousedown or mouseup in Chrome [possible bug in Chrome]?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Using the latest Chrome, I have notice that event `mousemove` fires after `mousedown` or `mouseup` even if the **mouse is left at the same position**.

I have this odd behavior attaching an event listener on `document.documentElement`.

Same script on latest Firefox works fine, issue seems on Chrome only.

- Why does this event fire?
- Is there any reasonable solution?

http://jsbin.com/cefoteleqo/1/

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
    console.log('mousedown', event.pageX, event.pageY);  
}.bind(this));
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
    console.log('mouseup', event.pageX, event.pageY);  
}.bind(this));
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    console.log('mousemove <<<<', event.pageX, event.pageY);  
}.bind(this));
```

Issue appears on Win 8.1:

- Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m
- Chrome Version 44.0.2398.0 canary (64-bit)

Comment: I can't replicate (Chrome 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) on OSX Yosemite) - I can get `mousedown` and `mouseup` with no `mousemove`.

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m on Win 8.1

Comment: I got the same problem, chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m - w8.1

Comment: With version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) on Mac, I get no mousemove with left click after mousedown then mouseup on left click but I do get mousemove for the same with right click.

Comment: I get it in 42.0.2311.135 as well. No issue on IE

Comment: i have the same problem on some windows clients. I made a workaround with CSS and Hover for my problem

Comment: probably related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161464

Comment: I have the same problem with v55.0.2883.75-1.

Comment: it is again: a mousemove after a mousedown Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (but only sometimes - after a browser restart it works correctly for a while...)

Comment: I have the same problem with Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) with OS-> Windows 7 : 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have notice that `mousemove` fire at the same time or within a really short distance (10 milliseconds) after `mousedown` pr `mouseup` are fired.

So a possible work is to use `event.timeStamp` on `mousemove` for comparisons.

The following script check if `mousemove` event fired "to soon" and print the result in console accordingly.

Another possible solution could be checking the position of the mouse when cb for `mousemove` is executed.

Both solution are just a work around to this [Chrome Bug.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161464)

Solution based on timeStamp:

http://jsbin.com/jedotomoxu/1/

Solution based on mouse position:

http://jsbin.com/dinororaju/1/

```
<script>
    var timeDownUp = null;
    function start() {
        document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
            timeDownUp = new Date().getTime();
            console.log('mousedown', event.pageX, event.pageY, event.timeStamp);
        }.bind(this));
        document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
            timeDownUp = new Date().getTime();
            console.log('mouseup', event.pageX, event.pageY, event.timeStamp);
        }.bind(this));
        document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
            var timeMove = new Date().getTime();
            timeDownUp += 10;
            if (timeMove > timeDownUp) {
                console.log('mousemove', event.pageX, event.pageY, event.timeStamp);
                if (event.which === 1) {
                    console.log('mousemove DRAG', event.pageX, event.pageY, event.timeStamp);
                }
            } else {
                timeDownUp = null;
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does the solution based on the mouse position does work in all cases? If the mouse has been moved diagonally the new X+Y coordinates might match the old X+Y coordinates.

Comment: Solution based on timeStamp: Working.. Solution based on mouse position: Not working

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well. The above solution was a bit too much for me. I am not sure if my solution works on all browsers but I can confirm it does work in the version of chrome I am currently running: Version 48.0.2564.109 m

```
svg.element.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoved);
svg.element.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);

var mouseDownTriggered = false;

function mouseDown(evt)
{
    console.log('mouse down');
    mouseDownTriggered = true;
}

function mouseMoved(evt)
{
    if (mouseDownTriggered)
    {
        mouseDownTriggered = false
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('mouse moved');
    }
}
```

I noticed the order is always mouse (down -> up -> moved) when you mouse down.
So I just flag the mouse down and have the mouse move absorb the call.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this approach. First, the behavior in my version of Chrome (54.0.2840.99 m) is that it only fires the mouseMove event *every other time you right click*. The other problem is this behavior doesn't happen in other browsers. So with this approach in other browsers and every other time you right click, the first legitimate mousemove event won't be fired. This might not be a problem for some implementations.